Updating Image without changing URL isn't updating Image
I'm using Next.js 14, have it hosted on Vercel, using Supabase as my database, and also using Cloudflare as a DNS.
I am running a website that has images and I get those image URLs from my Supabase DB. I'm usually NOT changing the URL.
I'm serving the images from my public folder so the URLs I have stored in Supabase usually looks like <domain>/<folder_name>/<file_name>.
Let's say I update the image itself in the public folder, but when I push a new build, the image being served is still the old image. However, if I go to the raw URL itself, the image is updated. But if I go to the _next/image?url=... this one is the old image.
Here is an example of my response headers for the image:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Age: 8
Cache-Control: public, max-age=60, must-revalidate
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="image-example-A.webp"
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'none'; frame-src 'none'; sandbox;
Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: cross-origin
Date: Mon, 29 Apr 2024 21: 7: 7 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 29 Apr 2024 21: 6: 6 GMT
Server: Vercel
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
Timing-Allow-Origin: *
Vary: Accept
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
X-Vercel-Cache: HIT

Here are the things I've tried:

Open console, empty cache & hard reload
Delete browser cache
Purge Vercel Data Cache
Purge Cloudflare Cache

None of these update the image.
However, if I add a query parameter to the image in my code such as ?v=1, then it'll automatically get the new image. However, I don't want this to be my only solution because then I'd have to update this whenever I need an immediate change and would prefer to press a button to purge the cache and have new images if I need to.
Another way it does update is after 12 hours, and I'm assuming it's because my Cloudflare Cache is set to 12 hours. So I'm guessing Cloudflare has something to do with it? But if that's the case, how come when I press Purge Everything on Cloudflare, nothing happens? I know it can take some time to propagate, but it's been an hour and it's still the same image.
How it also looks like my Vercel cache is set to 60 and even if it goes STALE it doesn't get the new image?
Is there something I'm missing / misunderstanding about caching with Vercel, Nextjs, Supabase, or Cloudflare? What else can I do to trigger a refresh without having to push new code?
Appreciate the help!

It's just because next.js generates some optimized versions of your images and store them. this cache is NOT flushed when you trigger a new deploy.
So you have some options:

You can play with the cacheTTL settings. Read this for more data: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#caching-behavior

Turn off the image optimization for a particular image (at the component level) or for all images (nextjs config file) if you don't need it.

Maybe you can write a new loader for your image optimization process. I don't know if it can help you but...


Also, if you are looking for way to flush all the image cache, I don't think there is one...
See this: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/37297#discussioncomment-5565492
Hope you can solve your problem 
